# XSLT 'when test' is not working correctly

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClaimSystemConfig>
   <MHC>
      <businessArea>Test2</businessArea>
   </MHC>
   <MHC>
      <businessArea>Test1</businessArea>
   </MHC>
   <PowerSTEPP>
      <businessArea>Test3</businessArea>
   </PowerSTEPP>
   <Amisys>
      <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
      <WADL>
         <url>Blah</url>
         <services>
            <service>
               <name>authSearch</name>
               <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
               <version>1</version>
            </service>
            <service>
               <name>memberSearch</name>
               <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
               <version>1</version>
            </service>
            <service>
               <name>memberSummary</name>
               <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
               <version>3</version>
            </service>
          </services>
      </WADL>
   </Amisys>
</ClaimSystemConfig>
```

Now, I want to modify the above xml using XSLT only if any one of the `<service>` tag has `<name>` as `memberSummary` and `<version>` as `3` . I am trying with the following condition, but it's not working.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]">
    ......do something.....
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    ...do nothing...    
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Can anybody help me on framing the correct condition?

Here is the partial XSLT:

```
  <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]">
                                <type>WADL</type>
                                <METHOD>POST</METHOD>
                                <service>memberSummary</service>
                                <requestSpecific>healthplan/memberstatuses</requestSpecific>
                                <inputSchema>
                                    <ver:routeData xmlns:ver="version3">
                                    </ver:routeData>
                                </inputSchema>
                                <parms>
                                    <parm>
                                        <name>eao</name>
                                        <value><xsl:value-of select="eao"/></value>
                                    </parm>
                                </parms>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>

                            </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: It would help if you explained in more detail about what is not working. Do you get an error message in this case, or unexpected output? Showing the expected output as well as your actual output would help a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @Tim C , When I test the condition outside using any Xpath Tester tool, it is returning me the result `Element='<service>
  <name>memberSummary</name>
  <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
  <version>3</version>
</service>'` , But when I incorporate the same change in my application, the control is not going in side `when` condition. Looks like something is wrong.

Comment: I think you need to show a bit more of your XSLT. If you can provide a complete, but minimal, example of the XSLT that demonstrates the problem, that would help. Are you sure it is even reaching the `xsl:choose` at all, for example?

Comment: @TimC, Added the XSL to the question now. Please take a look.

Comment: It appears that the control is going to `<otherwise> though the `when` condition is satisfied.

Comment: The `otherwise` condition is not outputting anything, so can you be sure it is even getting to the `xsl:choose` at all? Another thought.... Is your XML correct? Perhaps the actual XML uses namespaces, which would make a difference.

Comment: @TimC, yes..the xml is correct. When I place the same code without using `when` and `otherwise`, the code is executed...Something weird problem I am encountering....

Comment: Perhaps the context is wrong, e.g. a different document? Posting a fragment of XSLT that doesn't show the context is often a signal that the poster hasn't understood the importance of context.

Comment: I am sorry...Actually, the condition used for `when` should be loaded from another xml. Since the second xml is not available, the control is not going inside the condition. I have opened another thread for the problem.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355119/framing-a-condition-using-second-xml-content-in-an-xslt

Answer (score 2):

Currently, when you run the following XSLT on your XML the result is indeed "... do something ..."

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[3][name='memberSummary' and  version=3]">
            ......do something.....
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
            ...do nothing...    
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it will only "do something" if the `service` element in question is the third one in the list. So, you would need to change it to this:

```
<xsl:when test="//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]">
```