# Framing a condition using second xml content in an XSLT

Tags: xslt

I have to to modify an XML document using XSLT. Here the problem is: I have to modify the XML based on the node values of the another XML file. I have to use the following condition framed using the second XML.

```
//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and version=3]
```

First xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" SOAP:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <SOAP:Body>
      <performJob loadfromcache="yes">
         <jobName>PQLegacySecurity</jobName>
         <whiteboard>
            <PQ>
               <LegacySecurity>
                  <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
                  <LegacySystem>Amisys</LegacySystem>
                  <LegacyUserID>test</LegacyUserID>
                  <LegacyPassword>test@123</LegacyPassword>
                  <OtherLogin />
                  <OtherPassword />
                  <AddSecurLogin />
                  <AddSecurPassword />
               </LegacySecurity>
            </PQ>
         </whiteboard>
         <requestNodeName>//PQ</requestNodeName>
         <responseNodeName>//PQ</responseNodeName>
         <jobDB>
            <name>PQCustomerService</name>
            <userID>sa</userID>
            <password>password</password>
         </jobDB>
      </performJob>
   </SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

Second xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ClaimSystemConfig>
   <MHC>
      <businessArea>Test2</businessArea>
   </MHC>
   <MHC>
      <businessArea>Test1</businessArea>
   </MHC>
   <PowerSTEPP>
      <businessArea>Test3</businessArea>
   </PowerSTEPP>
   <Amisys>
      <businessArea>CSAAQA</businessArea>
      <WADL>
         <url>Blah</url>
         <services>
            <service>
               <name>authSearch</name>
               <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
               <version>1</version>
            </service>
            <service>
               <name>memberSearch</name>
               <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
               <version>1</version>
            </service>
            <service>
               <name>memberSummary</name>
               <tenant>rest/clientd/</tenant>
               <version>3</version>
            </service>
          </services>
      </WADL>
   </Amisys>
</ClaimSystemConfig>
```

XSLT code(something like below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <PQClaimSystemRequest>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//LegacySecurity" />
      </PQClaimSystemRequest>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="LegacySecurity">
      <request>
         <USERID>
            <xsl:value-of select="LegacyUserID" />
         </USERID>
         <PASSWORD>
            <xsl:value-of select="LegacyPassword" />
         </PASSWORD>
         <xsl:copy-of select="OtherLogin" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="OtherPassword" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="AddSecurLogin" />
         <xsl:copy-of select="AddSecurPassword" />
         <system>
            <xsl:value-of select="LegacySystem" />
         </system>
         <xsl:copy-of select="businessArea" />
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="LegacySystem = 'Amisys'">
               <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]">
                     <type>WADL</type>
                     <METHOD>POST</METHOD>
                     <service>memberSummary</service>
                     <requestSpecific>healthplan/memberstatuses</requestSpecific>
                     <inputSchema>
                        <ver:routeData xmlns:ver="version3" />
                     </inputSchema>
                     <parms>
                        <parm>
                           <name>eao</name>
                           <value>
                              <xsl:value-of select="eao" />
                           </value>
                        </parm>
                     </parms>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                     <type>WADL</type>
                     <METHOD>GET</METHOD>
                     <service>memberSummary</service>
                     <requestSpecific>healthplan/memberstatuses</requestSpecific>
                     <parms>
                        <parm>
                           <name>eao</name>
                           <value>
                              <xsl:value-of select="eao" />
                           </value>
                        </parm>
                        <parm>
                           <name>codeMatch</name>
                           <value />
                        </parm>
                        <parm>
                           <name>descriptionMatch</name>
                           <value />
                        </parm>
                     </parms>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
               </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:when>
         </xsl:choose>
      </request>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The condition `//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]` must be passed for the second xml to go inside the `when` 
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You forgot to explain what the problem is.

Comment: A small(!) example of the input XML, the "other" XML, and the required output would be useful, IMHO. -- Also pick either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: So you have a *string* in the second XML that is an XPath expression and you want that XPath expression to be evaluated in the first XML? That's not easy. If you have vanilla XSLT 1.0 without any extensions then it's even impossible. Post what XSLT processor you are using, exactly.

Comment: @Tomalak, I am thinking something like `<xsl:variable name="secondxml" select="document('another.xml')"/>` (or) `<xsl:copy-of select="document('another.xml'//ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]"/>
    </xsl:copy>` will help...but not sure..may be I need to modify..Do you have idea on these?

Comment: I see, so you're trying to *select* values from a second XML using a fixed XPath expression. Yes, that would work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save your second xml as `second.xml` and use the following instead of your current `xsl:when`:

```
<xsl:when test="document('second.xml')/ClaimSystemConfig/Amisys/WADL/services/service[name='memberSummary' and  version=3]">
```

Comment: That's what exactly I was looking for. Thanks.do you have any idea on using document() function with relative path?